# Can I embed this charger in a project?

Tags: arduino, batteries, lipo, charging

I have been attempting to create a portable arduino gaming system. While I have tried normal 'AA' or 'AAA' batteries, they are too large, so have decided to use a lipo battery. I now have this, but I would prefer to be able to recharge it without removing the battery, so need a charging board.

I have contemplated using the sparkfun single cell charger with a place for system out power (to the actual device), but it costs much more than I want to spend (it can be found here on Amazon: http://www.amazon.co.uk/LiPoly-Charger-Single-Cell-Input/dp/B004X7TZ9I/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1404232239&sr=1-2&keywords=sparkfun+battery+charger). I would like to use a very cheap generic board to charge the 3.7v lipo battery, but my question is: Can I embed this in my project and charge the battery without removing it.

My desired charger board can be found on Amazon here: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Generic-Lithium-Battery-Charging-Charger/dp/B00E39RGME/ref=pd_cp_ce_0

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why don't you put links to the circuit diagrams to avoid the clever folk having to wade thru countless pages of product detail.

Comment: Andy aka sorry but I thought there would be a standard for boards like these

Comment: Would you expect someone to repair your TV without a circuit diagram?

Comment: Andy aka again sorry for any ambiguity but as this question probably implies I have very little experience so would not know which pages are relevant, just as the vast majority of people would have no clue as to TV circuit diagrams

Comment: What I'm saying is that EE folk tend to work with circuit diagrams or schematics and in the absence of one cannot really help that much. Hopefully you may find someone who is familiar with these products but now it's less of an EE question/answer and more of a "tried and dunnit" problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your can attach a charger to the battery, and use the device at the same time.  There's nothing special about charging the battery versus using the battery.  The portion of the input power the device doesn't use, will go into the battery.

The only restrictions on this are that the charger isn't overloaded by the device's power requirements, and that the device doesn't take so much that the battery doesn't get a chance to charge.

Comment: How would I attach the wires from the charger to the device?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they're both functionally similar. The second board charges at 1A of current. The first board can charge at 100ma or 500ma. Either will work.

Good luck and be sure to revisit this question after your project is built to share your findings.